# Microsoft OAuth on behalf of user

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I have an application consisting of a front end (Vue) a backend (.NET) where I would like to do some actions in the Microsoft calendar of the user.(Create, update, delete, etc.). The goal is that when a user does a specific action in the front end and sends a request to the backend, the backend will do some actions with the microsoft graph api. Going through the Microsoft documentation I am a little confused as to where I am supposed to store the tokens I receive after authenticating the user.

[image]

I currently have a database in which my users are stored. Would it be correct to simply store the refresh token in that database and retrieve it whenever the backend needs to actions on behalf of the user? The documentation mentions storing the tokens as cookies in the browser but could I not simply store them in the backend?

Answer (score 1):

Your scenario looks like that your SPA calls your web API that calls Graph API.

In that case SPA can call your web API and provides a JWT token.

Your web API should validate the token and use the Microsoft Authentication Library (MSAL) `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` method to request another token from AAD so that your web API can call a Graph API, on behalf of the user.

Your web API can also call `AcquireTokenSilentlater` to request tokens for other APIs on behalf of the same user. `AcquireTokenSilent` refreshes the token when needed.

[A web API that calls web APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/scenario-web-api-call-api-overview)

Comment: What I don't understand here is a secret management. My Front-end app doesn't have any secrect involved and provides me access token. Now my Back-end app has a certificate for a secret but when I call `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` I got an exception: AADSTS50013: Assertion failed signature validation. [Reason - Key was found, but use of the key to verify the signature failed., Thumbprint of key used by client: '<some chars>', Found key '<my cert dates>'. 
Is this scenario anyhow eligible? If i got it right access token should be aquired using the same secret as provided in `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf`

Comment: So at my case I need to specifically provide authorization code to the backend and get token using certificate via `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`. But in this case `AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf` will be useless as my Back-end will already have the tokens anyway